# How to customize the "Cancel" button title in NSSavePanel?

Tags: macos, localization, nssavepanel

I can use the **-setPrompt:** method to customize the OK button. But I found no method to customize the Cancel one. Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no built-in way to replace this string. Out of curiosity, why do you want to? It should be displayed in the relevant language without your intervention, as with all other system-provided UI elements.

Comment: Mostly, curiosity. Secondly, I should know this if I tell my boss that "OK" can be customized. Because he would definitely ask me about the "Cancel" one. Anyway, thank you!